# Calculating the area of a parallelogram

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Calculating the area of a parallelogram with only two dimensions given such its base, $b$ and diagonal lengths. Can this be done or we need another information?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388118/calculating-area-of-a-parallelogram-using-length-of-two-diagonals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the area of a parallelogram can be determined using the diagonal lengths $d_1,d_2$ and the base length $b$.

[image]

The expression for the area is $\frac12d_1d_2\sin A$, where $A$ is the angle between the diagonals. For calculating $\sin A$, first find $\cos A$ using the cosine formula,$$\cos A=\frac{\left(\frac{d_1}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{d_2}2\right)^2-b^2}{2\left(\frac{d_1}2\right)\left(\frac{d_1}2\right)}$$and then use the fact $\sin A=\sqrt{1-\cos^2A}$.